# MySQL does not let me insert my values that contain single quotes ( ' )

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text area input and I'm trying to send to my database

"istanbul'un kanayan yarası olan ulaşım, özellikle anadolu yakasından kartal'dan kadıköy'e ulaşımın neredeyse 2 saate varması yüzünden perişan. devletin de politikaları aşikar. 17 ağustos günü verilen söz tutulur mu merak ediyoruz."

text.

it goes to >

```
$bahisaciklamax = $_POST["bahisaciklama"];
$bbb=str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $bahisaciklamax);
$bahisaciklama=strtolower(strip_tags($bbb, '<br><br /><br/><br />'));
```

and giving this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'un kanayan yarası olan ulaşım, özellikle anadolu yakasından kartal'dan kadıköy'e' at line 1
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You might start by showing us what your actual query and related code look like.

Comment: It look like not escaping the `'` in your string

Comment: Switching to a prepared statement should solve your problem (and more probably...)

Comment: $yaz=mysql_query("INSERT INTO bahis (bahisisim,bahisiaciklama,bahisacan,evet,hayir,sontarih,URL) VALUES ('$bahisisim','$bahisaciklama','$nickname','$evet','$hayir','$ddate','$url')");

Comment: Use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or whatever the equivalent is with the extension you're using?

Comment: if you are passing a value with extended chars first should send "SET NAMES UTF8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    // insert one row
    $name = 'one';
    $value = 1;
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: Careful only variables can be passed to bindParam not hard coded values else `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in ...` use bindValue if passing hard coded values